# How to decrease app size unity vuforia for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, filesize, vuforia

I have downloaded samples vuforia-samples-core-android-ios-unity-4-2-3.zip, open and build ImageTargets-4-2-3 for IOS. 
Then I build app in Xcode. 
The size of the app is 141,9 MB.
How can I decrease the size of the app?
Thanks!

Comment: When you build, go to the console, press the menu icon and open the "Open Editor Log" file. You will see a list of all the objects that are going into your build. You can post it here. A basic Vuforia build for iOS would probably be around 35MB once you export the .app to an .IPA.

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html and this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html

Comment: I have used this tips:
Set the iOS Stripping Level to Use micro mscorlib.

Set the script call optimization level to Fast but no exceptions.
which decrease size of the app above 20mb.

Comment: Here is the log:
http://txs.io/Iv6b
Please, point me, what should I find here?

Answer (score 0):

If you've downloaded and imported the full vuforia samples package then it will have quite a bit of content, in particular a couple of video files. It will also be supporting 64bit for iOS which adds a bunch of files to the project in comparison with before 64bit support. More info on Unity's site: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-64bit.html

You can also look at Unity's general recommendations for lowering the build size here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html